# Após validação laravel falhar, escolher um option de select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

Olá, pessoal, tenho duas combos: uma estados e uma cidades.

Quando eu escolho um estado, busco as cidades via ajax, da seguinte forma:

```
$('#estados').on('change', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    var id = e.target.value;

    /* busca as cidades de um determinado estado */
    $.get("{{ url('/administrador/buscar-cidades') }}/" + id, function(data) {
        //esvazia as cidades anteriores 
        $('#cidades').empty();
        $.each(data, function(index,subCatObj){
            //console.log(subCatObj);
            var option = new Option(subCatObj.nome, subCatObj.id);
            $(option).html(subCatObj.nome);
            $('#cidades').append(option);
        });
    });
});
```

Isso funciona perfeitamente. Porém, estou usando o laravel como backend e tenho 
uma validação no controller. Se a validação falhar, estou voltando pra página anterior com o id da cidade e desejo que a cidade seja novamente escolhida.

Eis a verificação:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
   return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput()->with('idCidade', $request->input('cidade_id'));
}
```

Para tal, adicionei o seguinte javascript para recarregar os estados:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#estados").find('option:selected').val() != "--Selecione--") {
        $("#estados").trigger('change');
    }
});
```

O que isso faz é basicamente fazer novamente o load das cidades caso a validação falhe, para preencher as cidades. E isso funciona.

O problema agora é eu conseguir pegar o ID da cidade que havia sido escolhido anteriormente, que foi passado do controller para a view, e escolher a cidade correta (que já havia sido escolhido antes da verificação).

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um `localStorage` com o código da cidade no *front-end* assim que for escolhida uma cidade no `select`:

```
$('#cidades').on('change', function(){
    localStorage.cidade = $(this).val();
});
```

No Ajax que carrega os Estados, puxe o `localStorage` caso ele esteja com algum valor:

```
$('#estados').on('change', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    var id = e.target.value;

    /* busca as cidades de um determinado estado */
    $.get("{{ url('/administrador/buscar-cidades') }}/" + id, function(data) {
        //esvazia as cidades anteriores 
        $('#cidades').empty();
        $.each(data, function(index,subCatObj){
            //console.log(subCatObj);
            var option = new Option(subCatObj.nome, subCatObj.id);
            $(option).html(subCatObj.nome);
            $('#cidades').append(option);
            if(localStorage.getItem("cidade") !== null){
                $('#cidades').val(localStorage.cidade);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Não esqueça de apagar o `localStorage` quando não precisar mais dele:

```
localStorage.removeItem('cidade');
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta. Me deu um norte. Tive que adicionar a verificação do localstorage no método .done do .get, pois precisa primeiro finalizar o preenchimento dos estados para depois eu buscar uma cidade.

Também adicionei um trigger de change em #estados ao inicializar a página.

Obrigado

Comment: @GabrielAugusto Legal! Obrigado!